# My commits got copied in in another project and my tags got moved

Tags: git, gitlab

I made a mess with my git repository by mistakingly changin teh remote address to the one of another project.

The result now is that all my commits from one roject got copied on to the other project with the exact same id.

Plus all the labels from the original project disappeared to magically be found only in the second project. Strange is I can only see them if I look in the tags as they are not linked to any branch.

**Original Project **
[image]
As you can see the commit id is the same in the two projects

**Second Project**
[image]
Those tags with related commit that you see here do not originally belong to this project.

What  I would like to do is ideally to restore all the labels in the original project (so move them back basically) and remove all those extra commits from the second project (there are a lot so the manual process  is a bit time consuming).

What  I found strange is that if I remove the tags from the second project then the commits also seems to magically disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, just a few explanations and suggestions how to fix the situaion.

If both projects have tags with same names, then you should take extra care while restoring their state. Generally, all alive commits in git should be referenced either by another commit or commits or by a named reference, that is a branch or a tag. So when you remove a branch or a tag  pointing to a commit, then there's a risk that the entire chain of commits may become orphaned and will be eventually garbage collected. Even if some commits disappeared, they may be accessible by their sha-1 for a while. Check `git reflog` for them.

The first thing you should do in these circumstances is to clone the broken repository into a clean local folder. Thus, you will preserve at least what remained. Also you should look for other clones of the repository (check your hard drive(s) thoroughly and ask colleagues), quite probably those copies contain correct info about tags and branches. Repository backups may help a lot in this case but who on Earth make backups *before*... Just kidding.

Once you've located a repo with at least some correct references, you may forcibly push those references to the broken remote repo as well as into the local copies. Use `git push -f <tagname>` but **do it with extra care**.

I'm not sure if gitlab.com provides backup services, but you also may ask them if they have a proper snapshot of the repository. Of course if your remote repo is located on gitlab.com, not on your own hosting.